# Open a singe list item with any other column than the ID?

Tags: custom-form, list-item, id

Is it possible by any means to open a single list item in a form using anything else than the list items unique ID?

I'm trying to open a dialog using a custom column which holds a unique 20 digit value to make sure that all list items have a random number generated on item creation. (The odds of my function generating this number twice is really, really low).

As an example i would be able to open a list item in a display form with the end of the URL being `/dispform.aspx?uId=123456789123456789` and never need to show the ID.

Sure, someone can always use F12 Developer Tools to find the list item ID, but i'm fine with that.

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot use different identifier in default SharePoint forms.
If you want use different identifier for load item in form, you should create your own form pages (display, edit, view) and use them.